# IBanimitable issue in xcode 9?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I am using cocoapod for ibanimatable.I was using it with xcode earlier and it was working fine.But now i when i updated the pod it has started giving me error.

```
public extension PlaceholderDesignable where Self: UITextField {

  var placeholderText: String? { get { return "" } set {} }

  public func configurePlaceholderColor() {
    let text = placeholder ?? placeholderText
    if let placeholderColor = placeholderColor, let placeholder = text {
      attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [.foregroundColor: placeholderColor])
    }
  }
}
```

Below line gives me error as

```
 attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [.foregroundColor: placeholderColor])
```

**Type 'String' has no member 'foregroundColor'**

Please tell me how can i get rid of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey), the attribute keys are not declared in `String`, but in `NSAttributedStringKey`. This means that you can't use the handy "just put a dot there and the compiler knows what you mean" syntactic sugar. The keys are strings, so the compiler thinks you meant `String.foregroundColor`, but obviously such a thing doesn't exist.

To fix this, write the type name properly:

```
NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: placeholderColor])
```

Comment: is it latest swift issue ? becuase i was using ibanimitable latest version

Comment: What do you mean by "swift issue"? If you mean "compiler bug" then no, this is expected behaviour. If you mean "issues with your swift code", the yes, you can't just omit the type name in this specific case. @DhirajKumar

Comment: I am saying it becuase this code is used by a very popular ios library IBANimitable.

Comment: It isn't related to `IBAnimatable`. You are just using the `NSAttributedString` wrongly. @DhirajKumar

Comment: Ok but i am saying like this because this code was in PlaceholderDesignable. PlaceholderDesignable is protocol under IBAnimitable

Comment: @DhirajKumar Are you using the correct version i.e. 5.x?

Comment: Yes i was using 5.0.0.I updated the pods to it.I am using xcode 9 with ios 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157346/discussion-between-sweeper-and-dhiraj-kumar).